# Change program IP address

Tags: tcp, ip, tcpclient

I have a TCP client/server app and I need change client IP address. If I open client app it will establish connection with server (inside client is defined IP adress of server - .exe file). Is there some way how can I define IP address which I want to connect? I did this once with port forwarding program, but it is little complicated and users need to use this program too, if they want to connect. Maybe some way where client get information that he is connected to the right IP, but he will connect to different, some what he don't have defined inside app.

But maybe this is just simply impossible :D . First sorry for my English I hope you will understand this, if not let me know and I will try to explain it a little more. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I don't have source code of application. Or how did u mean that? U mean set parameters in hosts file?

Comment: Yes, it is applicatation made in MMF and C++, but not made by me. And I don't have source code of it, I have just .exe file of client and server. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/167586). What is the problem you think this will solve exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the hostname that is coded in the app (if it is by hostname), you could write/rewrite the entry in the hosts file.

You possibly could find that with etherial or wireshark (or other packet sniffer).

If you have both the client and server apps, Im surprised there isnt a config file or setting that allows you to change this.  If it is a config file, you could re-write that entry...

Comment: So I will need to do it on every PC where client will be, right? Just for record, server app will be on VPS. But this is irrelevant information I think.

Comment: If there is a config file, you could pre-populate it with the proper ip, or when your users grab this pair of exe's you could give them a script the sets it.

Comment: There isn't config file. There is just one exe file (for client). Is possible make new exe file maybe in c# or something what will contain this exe file and script what will rewrite hosts file? Or how did u think "when users grab exe"?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle this is by cooperation between the client and the server. Simply have the client report the IP address it wishes to use to the server and have the server act as if the connection originated from that IP address. This method is used by [HTTP proxies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) and a similar method is used for SMTP (email).

Since you don't have the source code to the server or the client, some extra work will be needed.

You'll need to create your own client and server. Your client will connect to your server and tell it the IP it should be seen to be connecting from. Your server will note this. Then your client will launch the client executable.

You'll need to intercept the connection from the client on the server machine. Look up the IP address the connection is supposed to appear to come from. You'll need to hook the server executable's accept logic to see the IP address it's supposed to see rather than real IP address.

So the flow is:

1. Someone using the client machine launches the client executable, which is an executable you must make.
2. Your executable connects to a server application you must make and tells it the IP address it's supposed to be coming from.
3. Your server application notes the real source IP address and the one the client told it.
4. Your client application launches the regular client executable, it makes a connection to the server.
5. Your code on the server machine intercepts the server executable's code to accept this connection and substitutes the source IP address you stored in step 3.

Comment: Isn't this just for web? I need it for .exe applications.

Comment: @Koi No. This method is used by HTTP, SMTP, and even many generic proxies. Even if until now it's only been used for web, what stops you from using it for whatever purpose you want? You can use the [generic proxy protocol](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/enable-proxy-protocol.html#proxy-protocol) Amazon uses.

Comment: This looks little dificult for me :D :/ Maybe u could help me with that?

Comment: Presumably you asked how to do this because you thought it was the simplest way to solve whatever problem you had, but you didn't tell us what problem you have. Now that you see this isn't so easy, perhaps you can tell us your actual problem so we can see if there's an easier way to solve it.